# Unable to save null value in database even if tables columns set to "allow null"

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I am uploading a file into SQL Server using C# windows form application, but user will not always upload the file, if user directly presses save without using `OpenFileDialog` it should save null in database

My save button code is

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Read File Bytes into a byte array for attaching file
        byte[] FileData = ReadFile(txtpath.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CourierMaster(srno,OriginalPath,FileData)values(" + txtsrNo.Text + ",@OriginalPath, @FileData)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalPath", (object)txtpath.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileData", (object)FileData));
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (n > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record for "+txtsrNo.Text+" Inserted Successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Insertion failed");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

My Readfile() Function is

```
byte[] ReadFile(string sPath)
{
    //Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
    byte[] data = null;

    //Use FileInfo object to get file size.
    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
    long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

    //Open FileStream to read file
    FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    //Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

    //When you use BinaryReader, you need to supply number of bytes to read from file.
    //In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.
    data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

    //Close BinaryReader
    br.Close();

    //Close FileStream
    fStream.Close();
    return data;
}
```

I am getting error

> “The path is not of a legal form.”

In my ReadFile() function error occurs at this `FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);` line of code, I know we cannot assign a null to a path, But does it means I can’t save null in my database if it is a path?

Following is snap of my application:

[image: Application which accepts serial number through textbox and file through openfiledialogue]

Following is snap of my table:

[image: My table where srno is of numeric(18, 0), OriginalPath IS of varchar(MAX), FileData is of image datatype]

Comment: When you get an error from ReadFile, why are you suspecting the database as the root cause? I'd expect `sPath` to be invalid. Check what it contains.

Comment: while debugging sPath contains a null value i.e. ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before passing insert query I checked whether txtpath.Text is null or not, If it is null than I am not passing OriginalPath and FileData, Here is the code..

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtpath.Text == "")
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CourierMaster(srno)values(" + txtsrNo.Text +")", con);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] FileData = ReadFile(txtpath.Text);                        
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CourierMaster(srno, OriginalPath,FileData)values(" + txtsrNo.Text + ",@OriginalPath, @FileData)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalPath", (object)txtpath.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileData", (object)FileData));
        }
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (n > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record for "+txtsrNo.Text+" Inserted Successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Insertion failed");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the debugger and place a breakpoint on the line

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
```

You'll see that the value of `sPath` is something that isn't a valid path, and moving in the debugger callstack window to the method calling `ReadFile` you will be able to see what line created the problem (One of the path in your db is `" ."` or something like that that isn't a valid path).

Comment: while debugging value of path is ""

Comment: And it is an invalid value for a path, so either the value in you db is an empty string or a null value for this line. You shouldn't call your `ReadFile` method at all in this case (`string.IsNullOrEmpty` can tell you if it is the case)

Comment: So do I need to check if sPath is null or not im ReadFile() function?

Comment: Well 3 choices : **1.** Don't store invalid/null paths in your DB (might not be what you want), **2.** Check before calling `ReadFile` and so something else (Don't display the file, display an error, ...), **3.** check for this case in `ReadFile` and return a value that the calling code will understand (null, an empty array or a default file content)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do many things in conditional blocks,
instead of    `if (txtpath.Text == "")` you can also use    `if (txtpath.Text == null)`